# Repetitive email open webhook from Mailgun server

Tags: email, mailgun

I am getting repetitive email open callback for the users even though they only open email once.I am not sure this is a issue with mailgun open webhook call or something else is wrong

I would appreciate any kind of help on this

Thank you

Comment: Main problem with the open callback, it is coming even a user has deleted the email from his mailbox and mailgun is sending contineously the open callback to us.

Comment: Response we got from Mailgun support team for this :

" Unfortunately there is little we can do to prevent his from occurring. The opens you are seeing are occurring whenever the image pixel in the message is continually opened. We will log and return these opens everytime they occur and we do not have a way to determine if the open is occurring for a deleted message or not. " 

not much helpful :(